# WooCommerce - Update url when changing variation

Tags: javascript, jquery, woocommerce

I want to have the url to update accordingly when the user changes an attribute/variation on the product page.

I know there is a function (woocommerce_variation_select_change) in js that registers these changes, but how can I use them to update the url dynamically?

Hope someone can help or point me in the right direction

Comment: Sounds like ```Rewrite API``` type of solution!

Comment: In which file is that function? you could just listen to that and use `window.location.assign(url);` to change the url